# Separate pdf into n-page batches using command line

Tags: ubuntu, bash, pdf

I have a 8000 page PDF and I want to separate them into 500 page batches, i.e. pdf_1 has page 1-500, pdf_2 has page 501-1000, etc. (I don't want pdf of single pages like proposed in other solutions but a pdf of n pages, n=500 here)

Is there a way to do this using a script in Ubuntu?

I don't want to print it manually as I will have to do it many times. I hoped to be able to do this using a script

Comment: What platform? macOS could do this from the print dialog.

Comment: Ubuntu / Linux Platform

Comment: Then please add relevant information to your question.

Comment: macOS can print to pdf from the print dialog - which would make it quicker to do it manually than write a script to do it. You could even save as a preset. I've no idea on nix.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to install `qpdf`. Here's a quick attempt at a script.

```
#!/bin/bash

pdffile="$1"

# Find the nuber of pages in the document
qty=$(pdfinfo "$pdffile" | grep Pages | awk '{print $2}')

i=1      # first page for the file
j=500    # last page for the file
if [ $j -gt $qty ] ; then 
     echo "File is already smaller than 500 pages."
     exit 0
fi

while [ $j -le $qty ] ; do
    qpdf "$pdffile" --pages . $i-$j -- file.$i-$j.pdf
    i=$((i+500))     # on to the next 500...
    j=$((j+500))
    # If the remaining pages are less than 500, use qty as end.
    if [ $j -gt $qty ] ; then 
        j=$qty
    fi
    # ugly hack for if the number of pages is exactly n*500
    if [ $i -gt $qty ] ; then
        j=$((qty+100))
    fi
done
```

You can think about using a cli-argument instead of the 500, provide a nicer output file name etc. But this should give you a basic idea.